# Formalizing some items in an electrostatics computation

Tags: multivariable-calculus, electromagnetism

Consider the question attached (Example 3.4 from Zangwill's *Modern Electrodynamics*, Ch 3). I can follow the solution quite easily using "physics math" but, having just recently finished Spivak's *Calculus*, I want to formalize the operations performed and am hoping someone can help me with two items in particular. Note that I will refer to the equations in the attached picture as (1) through (6), in the order they appear. The only niceties which I intend to ignore in this "formalization" are the rigorous developments of the improper integrals and also the $\epsilon_0$ factor. All integrands etc. are continuous so all of the theorems I invoke apply.

1. For equation (3), I noted that Zangwill is choosing to evaluate the line integral along the path $ \boldsymbol\ell $ which is parametrized as $ \boldsymbol\ell  =  \boldsymbol\ell(r') = r' \mathbf{\hat{r}} $ in the conventional spherical coordinate system, and we are evaluating from $r'=\infty$ to $r' = r$. But I wanted to challenge myself to compute this line integral via the "opposite" path and to show that the same result obtains (as it must, since the line integral from a point to a point is independent of the parametrization of the path which we choose). Thus I tried to consider the parametrization $ \boldsymbol\ell  =  \boldsymbol\ell(u) = r'(u) \mathbf{\hat{r}} $ where $r'(u) = -u$ (perhaps this is my first error -- this was what I thought was appropriate for a path which "starts" at infinity and goes radially towards 0) where we go from $u = -\infty$ to $u = -r$. Thus $ d\boldsymbol\ell  =  \frac{d\boldsymbol\ell}{du}du = -\mathbf{\hat{r}}du $. Would this process be correct if I plugged it into the LHS equality of equation (3)?

2. More importantly, I want to follow the u-substitution which is performed using the physicist shorthand of "changing the integration variable". More rigorously (I think), I could observe that the middle expression in equation (3) is written as (I change the integration variable to $x$ so there is no confusion with derivatives)
   $$\int_\infty^r dx \ g'(x) (f\circ g)(x)$$
   where
   $$f (x) = \int_0^{1/x} ds \ s^2 \rho(s)$$
   $$g(x) = 1/x$$
   $$g'(x) = -1/x^2$$
   so that by the u-sub theorem (Spivak Theorem 19-2) I have
   $$\int_\infty^r dx \ g'(x) (f\circ g)(x) = \int_{g(\infty)}^{g(r)} dx f(x)=\int_{0}^{1/r} dx \int_0^{1/x} ds \ s^2 \rho(s)$$
   Integrating by parts (Spivak Theorem 19-1), I find then that the integral is given by
   $$\int_{g(\infty)}^{g(r)} dx f(x)=\int_{0}^{1/r} dx \int_0^{1/x} ds \ s^2 \rho(s) = \left(x\int_0^{1/x} ds \ s^2 \rho(s) \right)\Big|_0^{1/r} - \\ \int_{0}^{1/r} dx \ x (-1/x^2) (1/x)^2 \rho(1/x) = \frac{\int_0^{r} ds \ s^2 \rho(s)}{r} + \int_{0}^{1/r} dx \  \frac{\rho(1/x)}{x^3}$$
   where in the last step I've tried to use the fundamental theorem of calculus (Spivak Theorem 14-1) and the chain rule to evaluate the derivative with respect to $x$ of the inner integral. I can then observe that the second term integral in the above has an integrand of the form necessary for u-substitution, with $f(x) = x \rho (x), g(x) = 1/x, g'(x) = -1/x^2$ so that I obtain
   $$\frac{\int_0^{r} ds \ s^2 \rho(s)}{r} + \int_{0}^{1/r} dx \  \frac{\rho(1/x)}{x^3} = \frac{\int_0^{r} ds \ s^2 \rho(s)}{r} - \int_{\infty}^{r} dx \ x \rho(x) = \frac{\int_0^{r} ds \ s^2 \rho(s)}{r} + \\ \int_{r}^{\infty} dx \ x \rho(x) $$
   which is the correct final answer.

I'm hoping someone can check and/or set me straight with both steps.

[image]

Comment: Advice: Do not use $^\prime$ for a new variable when your work is full of derivatives (also with $^\prime$). Line integration is independent of parametrization, but going backwards on a path is a different path! Also, remember the physicists’ negative in the definition of potential of a conservative force. Your change of variable and substitution analysis are correct.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

1. See [Question about the sign of $\mathbf{E}\cdot d\mathbf{l} $when computing the Electric Potential](https://physics.stackexchange.com/a/686283/203278) for some remarks about the direction of the path, and its effect on signs (and indeed, you’re right that it doesn’t matter how you parametrize a path for line integrals of such conservative vector fields, as long as the endpoints are the same!, but the opposite path (i.e travsering a given path in the opposite direction) **will** yield a minus sign).
2. There was no need to change variables at all. The only thing being done here is integration by parts (and the FTC to evaluate $f’(x)$ in what follows). Let $f(x)=\int_0^x\rho(s)s^2\,ds$ (different from your $f$), and $g(x)=\frac{1}{x}$. Then, the integral in the middle is
   \begin{align}
   \int_{\infty}^rf(x)g’(x)\,dx&=[f(x)g(x)]_{\infty}^r-\int_{\infty}^rf’(x)g(x)\,dx\\
   &=\left[\frac{f(x)}{x}\right]_{\infty}^r-\int_{\infty}^r[\rho(x)x^2]\cdot\frac{1}{x}\,dx\\
   &=\frac{f(r)}{r}-0-\int_{\infty}^rx\rho(x)\,dx\\
   &=\frac{1}{r}\int_0^r\rho(s)s^2\,ds+\int_r^{\infty}x\rho(x)\,dx.
   \end{align}
   If you think about what you did, you made one change of variables, then you undid it, which is why your approach is longer than necessary.

Comment: First of all, thank you very much for your answer. I will review your linked answer to part one and get back to you, but I think it will clarify things for me. I've looked at the second part of the answer and understand, although I'm curious if you can comment -- it seems like Zangwill does not take this shorter route, and does indeed perform some u-substitution?

Comment: @EE18 no. Zangwill DOES NOT perform a u-substitution. he just wrote the IBP funny. He wrote $\int_{\infty}^rf\,dg=[fg]_{\infty}^r-\int_{\infty}^rg\frac{df}{dr}\,dr$, which apart from notation, has the same meaning as what I wrote.

Comment: Understood on all points on a second reading -- thank you again.

Comment: If you do get a chance, can I ask if you might consider taking a look at my other question: https://physics.stackexchange.com/questions/743736/coulomb-force-from-a-variational-principle -- I'll also be adding a bounty there once it becomes eligible too. It's really helpful to have someone as facile with the math as you to look at things that go above my head, so thank you again!